# Compute NDVI over each image in an image collection and export NDVI thresholded images

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, batch, iteration

I want to compute NDVI for all images in Sentinel2 (less than 20% cloud cover) in an image collection comprising 5 years. Thereafter, I want to batch export the output as a binary TIF file where NDVI <0.5 is ignored. Once I can do this, I will do the rest of the analysis in QGIS through a model that is ready to go.

Here's what I've done so far in bits and pieces to the best of my abilities.

```
//add study area
var studyarea = ee.FeatureCollection('users/XXX/XXXXX/studyarea');

Map.addLayer(studyarea, {color: 'red'}, 'study area');
Map.centerObject(studyarea);

//
/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

// Load the Sentinel-2 ImageCollection and bound to study area
var collectionSentinel2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2015-07-01', '2020-10-15')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20))
                  .filterBounds(studyarea)
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
                  .map(function(image){return image.clip(studyarea)});

//Mapping a Function over a Collection
var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};


//Applying NDVI to all images in the collection
var withNDVI = collectionSentinel2.map(addNDVI);

print (withNDVI);
```

So far so good apparently, but this is adding NDVI as a separate band, not sure if that's a good approach. Thereafter, here's the next bit of the code where I am thresholding NDVI images. I'm unable to use this as a function as with computing NDVI earlier.

```
//thresholding to extract healthy vegetation
//Identify all pixels below threshold and set them equal to 1. All other pixels set to 0
var ndvi_thrshld = ndvi.gt(0.50);  

//Remove all pixels equal to 0
ndvi_thrshld = ndvi_thrshld.updateMask(ndvi_thrshld); 

//Clip to study area        
var ndvi_thrshld_clipped = ndvi_thrshld.clip(studyarea);
```

To export to Drive, I am using the following code snippet which works great for a few images but not sure how to iterate it over the image collection.

```
// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ndvi_thrshld_clipped ,
  description: 'NDVI',
  scale: 10,
  region: studyarea,
  maxPixels: 18095956539
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out the answer myself. This seems to do the trick, sharing the entire code with anyone interested.

```
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');

//add study area
var studyarea = ee.FeatureCollection('users/XXX/XXXXX/studyarea');

Map.addLayer(studyarea, {color: 'red'}, 'study area');
Map.centerObject(studyarea);

//
/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

// Load the Sentinel-2 ImageCollection and bound to study area
var collectionSentinel2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2015-07-01', '2020-10-15')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20))
                  .filterBounds(studyarea)
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
                  .map(function(image){return image.clip(studyarea)});

//Mapping a Function NDVI over a Collection
var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  
  //Thresholding
  //If NDVI less or equal to 0.5 => 0 else 1
  var thres = ndvi.gte(0.5).rename('thres');
  
  return image.addBands(ndvi).addBands(thres);
};


//Applying NDVI to all images in the collection
var withNDVI = collectionSentinel2.map(addNDVI);

print (withNDVI);

//Export only the thres band
//SYNTAX - imageCollection.select([old bands], [new band names])
var bandSubset = withNDVI.select(['thres'], ['thres'])

batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(bandSubset, 'NEWFOLDER', 
                {scale: 10, 
                 region: studyarea.getInfo()["coordinates"], 
                 type: 'float'})
```